# Socrata query from Cold Fusion with a $where starts_with()

Tags: socrata, cfhttp

Good Morning,

I'm getting the following error:

errordetail:  string 400 Bad Request

filecontent:

string {"message":"Query coordinator error: query.soql.no-such-column; No such column: T; position: Map(row -> 1, column -> 1020, line -> \"SELECT `physician_profile_id`, `physician_profile_first_name`, `physician_profile_middle_name`, `physician_profile_last_name`, `physician_profile_suffix`, `physician_profile_alternate_first_name`, `physician_profile_alternate_middle_name`, `physician_profile_alternate_last_name`, `physician_profile_alternate_suffix`, `physician_profile_address_line_1`, `physician_profile_address_line_2`, `physician_profile_city`, `physician_profile_state`, `physician_profile_zipcode`, `physician_profile_country_name`, `physician_profile_province_name`, `physician_profile_primary_specialty`, `physician_profile_ops_taxonomy_1`, `physician_profile_ops_taxonomy_2`, `physician_profile_ops_taxonomy_3`, `physician_profile_ops_taxonomy_4`, `physician_profile_ops_taxonomy_5`, `physician_profile_license_state_code_1`, `physician_profile_license_state_code_2`, `physician_profile_license_state_code_3`, `physician_profile_license_state_code_4`, `physician_profile_license_state_code_5` ***WHERE starts_with(`physician_profile_first_name`,`A`)*** AND `physician_profile_city` = 'KNOXVILLE' AND `physician_profile_last_name` = 'ADAMS' AND `physician_profile_state` = 'TN' LIMIT 10}

What I'm attempted to do is pull physicians with the last name of Adams, first initial of A who are in Knoxville, TN.  AND 'physician_profile_first_name' = 'A' would be incorrect.  Any suggestions?  I am coding this in Cold Fusion using CFHTTP GET, just in case that helps.

Thank you,
CL

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message shown in your paste (`No such column`) you're referencing a column that doesn't exist in your query. Check the field names in your query against those in the dataset to make sure they're all valid.

Comment: Yes, due to trying to use the $where clause.  Haven't been able to figure out how else to find instances where the first name starts with the letter A.